# Bulk API 2.0 query returns truncated results when LIMIT clause not used

Tags: salesforce

version 47.0

Bulk API 2.0  ***NOT*** SOQL

Built up a python script using requests and requests_oathlib modules against test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token to generate access tokens
and a function that concatenates chunks of results until last chunk is detected then creates a json string from the results.

we *know* we have 1479552 rows in Contact.

The Problem:

```
    SELECT id,Name,Email,Phone FROM Contact LIMIT 1850000
```

produces

```
    ccntr: 0
    size of this  chunk: 113666341 bytes
    size of total chunk: 113666341 bytes
    Sforce-NumberOfRecords for this chunk: 1479553
    Sforce-Locator for this chunk: null
    =======================
    length of bigStr   : 113643182 chars
```

returns all 1479552 rows ( plus one header row ) but

```
    SELECT id,Name,Email,Phone FROM Contact
```

produces

```
    ccntr: 0
    size of this  chunk: 18952552 bytes
    size of total chunk: 18952552 bytes
    Sforce-NumberOfRecords for this chunk: 246370
    Sforce-Locator for this chunk: 246370
    -----------------------
    ccntr: 1
    size of this  chunk: 18943704 bytes
    size of total chunk: 37896256 bytes
    Sforce-NumberOfRecords for this chunk: 245824
    Sforce-Locator for this chunk: 492194
    -----------------------
    ccntr: 2
    size of this  chunk: 118 bytes
    size of total chunk: 37896374 bytes
    Sforce-NumberOfRecords not found
    Sforce-Locator not found
    =======================
    length of bigStr   : 37892718 chars
    total rows for decoded_content_list: 49219
```

returns only 492196 !!!
What is up with that??!!??

And I noticed that when using the LIMIT clause, only two chunks are returned, the first one contains all or close to all the data and the second only 110 bytes or so, while without the LIMIT  3 chunks of roughly equal size are returned.

There's more - with the LIMIT clause in place the one chunk returns with a header "Sforce-Locator" with a value of 'null' - a valid string. Notice that in the last chunk of the result without the LIMIT clause there is no Sforce-Locater header ***at all*** . So the behavior is different on at least two fronts.

Can anyone verify and/or explain this behavior? Better still, tell me how to get around it?

Bonus question: SOQL returns the columns in the same order as listed in the SELECT statement, as expected. But when the same statement is executed using Bulk API 2.0 the results come back with columns sorted in alphabetical order i.e. Email, id, Name, Phone. This is not an artifact of python's not maintaining order in dicts, I've checked the raw csv data returned by the query before it gets converted to JSON.

Some code snippets

```
    def getBulkQueryResults( url_to_use, access_token, operation_id, isDebug=False):
      finished = False
      bio = io.BytesIO()
      url_full = "{0}/jobs/query/{1}/results".format( url_to_use, operation_id)
      while not finished:
        r = requests.get(url_full, headers=headers ) # an object of type Response 
        header_dict = r.headers
        bio.write( r.content)
        if( 'Sforce-Locator' not in header_dict): # this may be the problem
          finished = True
        else:
          url_full = url_full + '/?locator=' + header_dict['Sforce-Locator']
      totbio = bio.getvalue()
      bigStr = totbio.decode('utf-8')
      decoded_content_list = bigStr.split('\n')
      print( "=======================")
      print( "length of bigStr   : {0} chars".format( str( len(bigStr))))
      print( "total rows for decoded_content_list: {0}".format ( str( len( decoded_content_list))))
      json_str = convertCsvListToJsonStr( decoded_content_list, isDebug)
      return json_str

    def executeBulkQuery( url_to_use, access_token, query_to_use, isDebug=False):
      if isDebug: print( "executeBulkQuery - entered")
    # to to retrieve some data
      headers = { 'Authorization' : "Bearer {0}".format( access_token)
                , 'Content-Type'  : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                , 'Accept'        : "application/json"
                }
      boddy_dict   = { 'operation' : "query" , 'query' : query_to_use }
      boddy_json   = json.dumps( boddy_dict)
      url_full = "{0}/jobs/query".format( url_to_use)
      r = requests.post( url_full, headers=headers, data=boddy_json )
      r_dict = r.json()
      query_id = r_dict['id']
      finished = False
      while not finished:
        if( checkBulkQueryStatus( url_to_use, access_token, query_id) == "JobComplete"):
          finished = True
      json_str = getBulkQueryResults( url_to_use, access_token, query_id, isDebug)
      return json_str
```

TIA,

code_warrior

Comment: Same user connecting (same permissions, sharing rules etc?). Are you sure second script waited till the job was marked completed? What do you see in SF Setup -> Bulk data load jobs? Or getting job stats by id, like in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/query_walkthrough.htm ?

Comment: Yes, same everything. And my while-loop periodically checks job stats, exiting on  state='JobComplete' or chunk-cntr > 100

Comment: This may be hard to solve without some code. Can you share a minimal reproduction?

Comment: added some code snippets. I think the issues can be worked around by adjusting the line so commented. Thx for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Subtle: this statement:

```
    url_full = url_full + '/?locator=' + header_dict['Sforce-Locator']
```

keeps appending ?locater with each iteration. Solution is to rewrite it to

```
    url_full = "{0}/jobs/query/{1}/results?locator={2}".format( url_to_use, operation_id, header_dict['Sforce-Locator'])
```